# WPF button style StaticResource value from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Based on my very fresh understanding about WPF, I can set the value in my ViewModel and bind the variable to WPF control for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [SomeViewModel].selfdefinedText}"/>
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to apply the same way to StaticResource? As below is usually the way I refer to ResourceLibrary:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource somestyle}"/>
```

Now instead of hardcoding the `somestyle` here, can I bind a variable that defined in my viewModel instead?

Something like below:

In my ViewModel:

```
public string TestStyle
{
    get{ return _TestStyle;}
    set{ SetProperty(ref _TestStyle, value);}
}

TestStyle = "someStyle";
```

Then in my XAML:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource [SomeViewModel].TestStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VM is exposing a `Style` directly (probably a bad idea), you would just:

```
<Button Style="{Binding SomeStyleViaViewModel}"/>
```

If, on the other hand, your VM is exposing the *key* for the style, you would need a converter:

```
<Button Style="{Binding SomeStyleKeyViaViewModel, Converter={StaticResource MyStyleConverter}}"/>
```

Your converter would basically need to look up the `Style` based on the key.

Comment: Basically my idea just to pass a string from viewModel to the button style

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to achieve this is to define the `AttachedProperty` (`MyStyle`) and set it on the `Button`. Depending on the value of property Style will be searched and applied to the `Button`.

Attached property will look like:

```
public static class MyStyles
{
    static FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                     string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, MyStylePropertyChangeCallBack);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyStyle", typeof (String), typeof (MyStyles), metadata);

    public static void SetStyleName(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MyStyleProperty, value);
    }
    public static Boolean GetStyleName(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Boolean)element.GetValue(MyStyleProperty);
    }


    public static void MyStylePropertyChangeCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        FrameworkElement ctrl = d as FrameworkElement;

        if (ctrl.IsLoaded)
        {
            string styleName = Convert.ToString(e.NewValue);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(styleName))
            {
                ctrl.Style = ctrl.TryFindResource(styleName) as Style;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in xaml:

```
<Button local:MyStyles.MyStyle="{Binding TestStyle}" />
```